# Are Python addresses compared as strings or ints?

Tags: python, comparison, memory-address, comparison-operators

In [`__cmp__`](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__cmp__)` I read:

If no `__cmp__(), __eq__() or __ne__()` operation is defined, class instances are compared by object identity (“address”).

From [5.3 Comparisons](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html):

CPython implementation detail: Objects of different types except numbers are ordered by their type names; objects of the same types that don’t support proper comparison are ordered by their address.

Does identity mean the value returned by the id() function (a long int)?

So are addresses compared as if they were ints? Or are they compared as strings?

I tried to write my own example but I can't figure out how.

Comment: They're ordered by int, but why does this implementation detail matter to you? It's a Bad Idea to try to order objects of different types anyway (in Python 3, it's just an error, sensibly).

Comment: it is just a curiosity I couldn't find an answer. Anyway, I was referring to ordering objects of the same type without a redefinition of the \__lt__ method. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

The address/identity is returned with `id()` and this returns an integer value, so yes, they are ordered as ints.

From the official documentation:

> id(object)
>
> Return the “identity” of an object. This is an integer (or long integer) which is >guaranteed to be unique and constant for this object during its lifetime. Two objects >with non-overlapping lifetimes may have the same id() value.
>
> CPython implementation detail: This is the address of the object in memory.

Test it yourself. Open an interactive console and write the following:

```
>>> class Test(object):
>>>     pass
>>> test1 = Test()
>>> test2 = Test()
>>>
>>> print id(test1), id(test2)
35677712 35678128   # You can see the second one is bigger. Both integers!
>>>
>>> print test1 > test2
False
>>> print test1 < test2
True
```

Anyway this has no use at all. And in Python 3 raises an Error

Comment: I would appreciate an explanation for the downvoting.

Comment: Not my downvote, but you'd get the same result if the ids were ordered lexically, since they both have the same number of digits. This doesn't particularly prove anything.

Comment: Do you mean that I did not make clear that they are ordered by address being the address an `int`? If so, I assumed that it's clear that `id()` returns an integer, but I included now in the answer.

Comment: The OP already knows `id()` returns an `int`; that's in the question. Your last 2 `<` and `>` comparisons don't prove that strings aren't being used internally (granted, it would be really stupid for cpython to convert the pointer addresses into strings to compare them, and I don't know why the question is even being asked...)

Comment: It seems you are right, I misunderstood the question.

Comment: The problem is that addresses in all my tests have always the same number of digits so in general one can't say if they are compared lexicographically or as numbers, and I can't figure out how to make that explicit through an example.

I don't know why but I always have the feeling that the Python system uses strings a lot, and I wouldn't be surprised if the address were stored and compared as strings (even though it wouldn't make sense).

As why the question has been asked, it's just a curiosity.

Comment: Comparing ints by converting them to strings is nonsensical... I doubt that even PHP would do that :)